# Spring: Accessing Request (Session) Scoped Bean from Web App Thread Child Threads (from ThreadPool)

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, http, lambda

We have a Spring web application. API is implemented with Jersey while the webserver is jetty.

We want to be able to access request scoped bean from parallel lambda expressions and multicasted Apache Camel routes, initialized by the parent thread.

It is possible to let child threads inherit request context from the parent thread (via InheritableThreadLocal variables). Though the issue is that those properties are **not passed to child threads** as they are **re-used from the threadpool** (separate lambda and camel's).

It is not possible to pass the request bound information via parameters either - we have  too many methods in the project that would need to be changed.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by first getting the parameters

```
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
RequestAttributes attributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();
```

And setting them inside your thread like

```
SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attributes, true);
```

I was facing the same problem in my application reading the file as the input of a rest request parsing it line by line and inserting records into the database.

But the file contains more than 5 lac records and the process was taking too much time. SO I decided to go with the parallel stream.

Below code worked for me

```
public void saveRecordsFromFile(MultipartFile file) {

    // Getting security and request params
    SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    RequestAttributes attributes = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()))) {

        // Reading the file line by line and making rule
        br.lines().parallel().forEach(line -> {

            // Setting security and request params for current thread
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);
            RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(attributes, true);

            saveRecord(line);

        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new SystemException("Error while input file", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Naresh! perfectly worked out for me. Tried so many other things but could resolve my issue with this trick.